# How to create a element in another html page with a button click

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<button id="sendDiv">send</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#sendDiv').click(function() {
    var x = true;

    if (x === true) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'store';
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.store {
    background: lightgrey;
    width: 60%;
    height: 200px; }
```

So if I click on the button i will create a div with a color but how do I create it in a another html page ? .. lets say when i click on the button, a div should be created in a another page

Comment: What other page? Where is it? How is it loaded?

Answer (score 0):

you can't if the page is not loaded..
unless you mean writing to the other page's source code?